# Regex Expression to Find 5-Digit Code

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

Trying to find pattern matches based on the following conditions:

- Length of string is 5 characters
- Char [0] = Letter/Number
- Char [1] = Letter
- Char [2-4] = Number

I don't understand why "22222" works for this expression?

```
 p = r'(\w|\d)(\w)(\d){3,}'
 m = re.match(p, "AA012")    # Works as expected
 --> 'AA012'

 m = re.match(p, "1A222")    # Works as expected
 --> '1A222'

 m = re.match(p, "22222")    # Does NOT work as expected!
 --> '22222'
```

What am I missing in my regex expression syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\w` matches letters *and* digits (as well as underscores).

Use `[a-zA-Z]` if you want to match *only* letters:

```
r'\w[a-zA-Z]\d{3,}'
```

which matches a letter or digit (or an underscore), then a letter, then 3 digits.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> p = r'\w[a-zA-Z]\d{3,}'
>>> re.match(p, "22222")
>>> re.match(p, "AA012")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x105aca718>
>>> re.match(p, "1A222")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x105aca780>
>>> re.match(p, "_A222")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x105aca718>
```

If the underscore is a problem, use:

```
r'[a-zA-Z\d][a-zA-Z]\d{3}'
```

Comment: I guess you'd also need anchors, since the strings are always of length 5.

Comment: `facepalm` I need to read documentation more carefully! This makes sense.