# Remove US zip codes from a string: R regex

Tags: regex, r

I am attempting to remove/extract zip codes from a character string.  The logic is that I am grabbing things that:

1. must contain exactly 5 consecutive digits OR
2. must contain exactly 5 consecutive digits followed by a dash and then exactly 4 consecutive digits OR
3. must contain exactly 5 consecutive digits followed by a space and then exactly 4 consecutive digits

The zip portion of string could start with a space but might not.

Here's a MWE and what I've tried. The 2 attempted regexes are based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/578406/what-is-the-ultimate-postal-code-and-zip-regex) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25180752/regex-to-extract-us-zip-codes-but-not-faux-codes):

```
text.var <- c("Mr. Bean bought 2 tickets 2-613-213-4567",
  "43 Butter Rd, Brossard QC K0A 3P0 – 613 213 4567", 
  "Rat Race, XX, 12345",
  "Ignore phone numbers(613)2134567",
  "Grab zips with dashes 12345-6789 or no space before12345-6789",  
  "Grab zips with spaces 12345 6789 or no space before12345 6789",
  "I like 1234567 dogs"
)

pattern1 <- "\\d{5}([- ]*\\d{4})?"
pattern2 <- "[0-9]{5}(-[0-9]{4})?(?!.*[0-9]{5}(-[0-9]{4})?)"


regmatches(text.var, gregexpr(pattern1, text.var, perl = TRUE)) 
regmatches(text.var, gregexpr(pattern2, text.var, perl = TRUE)) 

## [[1]]
## character(0)
## 
## [[2]]
## character(0)
## 
## [[3]]
## [1] "12345"
## 
## [[4]]
## [1] "21345"
## 
## [[5]]
## [1] "12345-6789"
## 
## [[6]]
## [1] "12345"
## 
## [[7]]
## [1] "12345"
```

**Desired Output**

```
## [[1]]
## character(0)
## 
## [[2]]
## character(0)
## 
## [[3]]
## [1] "12345"
## 
## [[4]]
## character(0)
## 
## [[5]]
## [1] "12345-6789" "12345-6789"
## 
## [[6]]
## [1] "12345 6789" "12345 6789"
## 
## [[7]]
## character(0)
```

**Note** *R's regular expressions are similar to other regex but are specific to R.  This question is specific to R's regex not a general regex question.*

Comment: I am not sure a bout the note. When you use `perl=TRUE` for example , you can alos use perl regex so generally the classical regex is an R solution.

Comment: @agstudy More along the lines of doubling up back slashes and any other R specific regex things (I don't know regex well enough to know what these things are but I've found non-R users' regexes often don't translate to R).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Lookaround assertion

You can use a combination of [**Negative Lookbehind**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#lookarounds) and a word boundary `\b` here.

```
regmatches(text.var, gregexpr('(?<!\\d)\\d{5}(?:[ -]\\d{4})?\\b', text.var, perl=T))
```

**Explanation**:

- The negative lookbehind asserts that what precedes is not a digit.
- Word boundary asserts that on one side there is a word character, and on the other side there is not.

  ```
  (?<!        # look behind to see if there is not:
    \d        #   digits (0-9)
  )           # end of look-behind
  \d{5}       # digits (0-9) (5 times)
  (?:         # group, but do not capture (optional):
    [ -]      #   any character of: ' ', '-'
    \d{4}     #   digits (0-9) (4 times)
  )?          # end of grouping
  \b          # the boundary between a word character (\w) and not a word character
  ```

### Additional options

You may consider using the `stringi` library package which performs faster.

```
> library(stringi)
> stri_extract_all_regex(text.var, '(?<!\\d)\\d{5}(?:[ -]\\d{4})?\\b')
```

Comment: Works well.  Thank you.  The comments are also very helpful!

Comment: Just saw you have a regex explaining tool: http://liveforfaith.com/re/explain.pl  Very cool :-)  Also I'm turning a number of these regexes into a quickie R package.  I'd like to give you contributor authorship on the package with a name beyond SO's hwnd.  If you'd like you're actual name used please send an email https://github.com/trinker

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regex like this:

```
"(?<!\\d)(\\d{5}(?:[-\\s]\\d{4})?)\\b"
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/eO3zA3/3)**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me, and gave the desired output on all of your examples:

```
"(?<!\\d)(\\d{5}(?:[- ]\\d{4})?)(?!\\d)"
```

Answer (score 1):

## RegEx with LookArounds:

```
(?<![0-9-])([0-9]{5}(?:[ -][0-9]{4})?)(?![0-9-])`
```

Live demo: http://regex101.com/r/hU9oK4/1

**The stuff we're after:**

- `[0-9]{5}` is the most *important* part, looking for exactly 5 digits
- `(?:[ -][0-9]{4})?)` optionally followed by 4 more BUT only if joined by a space or minus sign

**Boundaries, boundaries, boundaries:**

- `(?<![0-9-])` first group: Negative LookBehind (makes sure there is no digit or dash)
- `(?![0-9-])` last group: Negative LookAhead ( —||— *same pattern...*)

**Extra test case:**

> another zip 09788-4234has no space after
> 98712
> 987122
> zip or range 12987-19222 ?
> what about this serial 88101-8892-22912-9991-99101 ?
> 90872-8881

### Why?

- LookArounds don't `consume` characters
- you shouldn't be picking up *false positives* (eg. the first or last 5 digits from a longer no.)
- ZIP might be on it's own line, or at the very beginning or end
- you could bump into a *space-less* address
- 5 digits starting with a minus sign should not be a zip code

**Final notes:**  this is not intended to be a ***final*** or bulletproof match code, you might still collect some zip lookalikes, especially because of the space between the digit groups in your requirement

<sub>**Personal note:** I find `[0-9]` character classes clearer *and easier to understand* for newcomers to RegEx even if they're included in a `\d`, but they're also faster and have a better compatibility between RegEx flavours. On the other hand, double escapes (eg. `\\d` are an ugly read)</sub>

Comment: Double escapes are needed in R

Comment: @hwnd indeed and also `[0-9]` *bypasses* the need to double escape `\d`

Answer (score 0):

The `qdapRegex` package has the `rm_zip` function (based on @hwnd's response) for this:

```
rm_zip(text.var)
rm_zip(text.var, extract=TRUE)

> rm_zip(text.var, extract=TRUE)
[[1]]
[1] NA

[[2]]
[1] NA

[[3]]
[1] "12345"

[[4]]
[1] NA

[[5]]
[1] "12345-6789" "12345-6789"

[[6]]
[1] "12345 6789" "12345 6789"

[[7]]
[1] NA
```