# With R, when string extraction creates a list element in a data frame, how can you add a row for each item in the list?

Tags: regex, r, qdapregex

I have hundreds of addresses in a data frame variable and need to extract zip codes from them.  Some of the addresses contain more than one city, each with a zip code.  Here is a mock example of a data frame and R code that extracts the zip codes.

```
require(qdapRegex)
require(stringr)

df <- data.frame(address = c("Walnut; 94596, Ontario, 91761, Beach, CA 90071", "Irvine Cal 92164"), var2 = "text")
df$zip.Rinker <- sapply(df$address, FUN = rm_zip, extract=TRUE)
```

The `rm_zip` function from Tyler Rinker's `qdapRegex` package extracts all the zip codes and puts them in list if there is more than one.

```
> df
                                         address var2          zip.Rinker
1 Walnut; 94596, Ontario, 91761, Beach, CA 90071 text 94596, 91761, 90071
2                               Irvine Cal 92164 text               92164
```

How can R create a new row for each zip code that is in row 1 under zip.Rinker?  Something like the following would be ideal.  Note, there will be dozens of addresses that have multiple zip codes, so I am hoping for a solution that doesn't require manual steps.

```
                                         address var2          zip.Rinker
1 Walnut; 94596, Ontario, 91761, Beach, CA 90071 text               94596
2 Walnut; 94596, Ontario, 91761, Beach, CA 90071 text               91761
3 Walnut; 94596, Ontario, 91761, Beach, CA 90071 text               90071
4                               Irvine Cal 92164 text               92164
```

Thank you for time.

PS Using `stringr`, this code extracts zip codes and presents the same challenge.

```
df$zip.stringr <- str_extract_all(string = df$address, pattern = "\\d{5}")
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Split string and insert as new rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15347282/split-string-and-insert-as-new-rows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
data.frame(rep(df$address, sapply(df$zip.Rinker, length)), unlist(df$zip.Rinker)

##   rep.df.address..sapply.df.zip.Rinker..length.. unlist.df.zip.Rinker.
## 1 Walnut; 94596, Ontario, 91761, Beach, CA 90071                 94596
## 2 Walnut; 94596, Ontario, 91761, Beach, CA 90071                 91761
## 3 Walnut; 94596, Ontario, 91761, Beach, CA 90071                 90071
## 4                               Irvine Cal 92164                 92164
```

But note that `rm_zip` is already vectorized and pretty speedy as it wraps the `stringi` package.  So no need for `sapply`.  Here's an approach that makes the code much more condensed using `qdapTools`'s `list2df` that takes a named `list` of vectors and turns them into a `data.frame`.

```
library(qdapTools)
list2df(setNames(rm_zip(df$address, extract=TRUE), df$address), "zip", "address")[, 2:1]

##                                          address   zip
## 1 Walnut; 94596, Ontario, 91761, Beach, CA 90071 94596
## 2 Walnut; 94596, Ontario, 91761, Beach, CA 90071 91761
## 3 Walnut; 94596, Ontario, 91761, Beach, CA 90071 90071
## 4                               Irvine Cal 92164 92164
```

And I like the `magrittr` framework for nested functions so here's that:

```
library(qdapTools)
library(magrittr)

df$address %>%
    rm_zip(extract=TRUE) %>%
    setNames(df$address) %>%
    list2df("zip", "address") %>%
    `[`(, 2:1)
```

Comment: very nice.  Does your call need one more parenthesis at the end?

Comment: Nice solution sticking to the qdap package (+1)

Comment: @lawyeR I don't think it needs another parenthesis.  I included a `magrittr` solution as this helps sort out nested calls like this.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach using "data.table" and `gregexpr`/`regmatches`:

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(df)[, c(.SD, Zips = unlist(list(
  Zips = regmatches(address, gregexpr("\\d{5}", address))))), 
  by = 1:nrow(df)]
#    nrow                                        address var2  Zips
# 1:    1 Walnut; 94596, Ontario, 91761, Beach, CA 90071 text 94596
# 2:    1 Walnut; 94596, Ontario, 91761, Beach, CA 90071 text 91761
# 3:    1 Walnut; 94596, Ontario, 91761, Beach, CA 90071 text 90071
# 4:    2                               Irvine Cal 92164 text 92164
```

Comment: I must be doing something wrong.  I get this > as.data.table(df)[, c(.SD, Zips = unlist(list(
+   Zips = regmatches(address, gregexpr("\\d{5}", address))))), 
+   by = 1:nrow(df)]
Error in `[.data.table`(as.data.table(df), , c(.SD, Zips = unlist(list(Zips = regmatches(address,  : 
  j doesn't evaluate to the same number of columns for each group

Comment: @lawyeR, I just double-checked, posting the same code above, and it worked without a problem for me. What version of "data.table" are you using?

Comment: I am using Version 1.9.2 of data.table.  Sorry to bother you.  I will re-install and try again

Comment: @lawyeR, OK. I think 1.9.4 is on CRAN now, so you can try that and see if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach using just the `stringi` package:

```
library(stringi)
zip <- stri_extract_all_regex(df$address, "\\d{5}") 
data.frame(address=rep(df$address, sapply(zip, length)), zip=unlist(zip))

##                                          address   zip
## 1 Walnut; 94596, Ontario, 91761, Beach, CA 90071 94596
## 2 Walnut; 94596, Ontario, 91761, Beach, CA 90071 91761
## 3 Walnut; 94596, Ontario, 91761, Beach, CA 90071 90071
## 4                               Irvine Cal 92164 92164
```

Answer (score 0):

One more approach, this one using only base R with hwnd's regular expression for extracting zip codes [Remove US zip codes from a string: Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25223792/remove-us-zip-codes-from-a-string-r-regex/25223890#25223890)

```
match <- gregexpr('(?<!\\d)\\d{5}(?:[ -]\\d{4})?\\b', df$address, perl=T)
zips <- regmatches(df$address,match)
nn <- rep(1:length(match),sapply(zips,length))
data.frame(df[nn,], zip=unlist(zips))

                                          address var2   zip
1   Walnut; 94596, Ontario, 91761, Beach, CA 90071 text 94596
1.1 Walnut; 94596, Ontario, 91761, Beach, CA 90071 text 91761
1.2 Walnut; 94596, Ontario, 91761, Beach, CA 90071 text 90071
2                                 Irvine Cal 92164 text 92164
```