# Extract some data from string php

Tags: php, extract

Quick question to easily cut a string. I know the substr but I can not use it in my case.

I have for example this thong: "1 rue Maryse Bastie 69500 BRON"
I'd like to say "Get all the end before the numbers" in this case "BRON" and get the numbers. I want the city and the postalcode in difference variable.

The API I'm using returns the complete address but I'd like to cut out to save the city and postal code in a different table.

I think this subject can help me : [Extracting a zip code from an address string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21074812/extracting-a-zip-code-from-an-address-string) but not to get the city.

For exemple, if i have `1 rue Maryse Bastie 69500 BRON`
I want $city = "BRON" and $pc = "69500"

If i have `13 rue Hohwald 67000 Strasbourg`
I want $city = "Strasbourg" and $pc = "67000"

Thanks

Comment: what exactly do you want it to return. should it return 69500?

Comment: I think regex can help you, please check about `preg_match` in php

Comment: Please show us what you've tried, what result you're expecting and what you're currently getting and we can help you sort that out. Also, what variations of that string can there be? Are they always in the same format or can they differ?

Comment: Yes i want a var with "69599" and another with "BRON"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I give you a workaround, it should totally works, but maybe you will have to improve it :

```
$test = '1 rue Maryse Bastie 69500 BRON';
\preg_match('/\b\d{4,5}.+$/i', $test, $out);
$output = \explode(' ', \trim($out[0]), 2);
var_dump($output);
/*
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "69500"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "BRON"
}
*/
```

In the code above we have used regex to find this way :

- find digits (many characters --> 4 or 5 five for french zipcode)
- find all characters next the zipcode until the end

Next we remove spaces at start and end, then we split into an array.

Comment: Its work fine, just a small problem. For exemple, a city was call "St Quentin", the code display only "St"

Comment: In this case you can limit the explode with an third argument like this : `$output = \explode(' ', \trim($out[0]), 2);` It will split string into an array of two items, so only split at first space encountered. I edit my answer for your case.

Comment: The problem its how to know if they have 2 argument or 1 ?

Comment: This will be everytime limited to `2`, `$output = \explode(' ', \trim($out[0]), 2);` will be correct in all cases. I tested in all cases like `1 rue Maryse Bastie 69500 ST BRON EN YVELINES, 13 rue Hohwald 67000 Strasbourg`.

Comment: It's work ! Thanks man. Thanks a lot for your help ! :) Good evening

Comment: The case-insensitive flag serves no purpose.

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting your string in the same format as you mentioned in your question, you can break the string into an array and collect the last two elements as you required values.

Let me show you.

```
$myString = "1 rue Maryse Bastie 69500 BRON";
$breakUP = explode(" ", $myString);
$totalElement = count($breakUP);
$city = $breakUP[$totalElement - 1]; // Last element
$zip = $breakUP[$totalElement - 2]; // Second Last element
```

Hope this helps you :)

Comment: Thanks for your help mail2bapi. Just, for example i have one city call "St Quentin". So your script return $city = Quentin, $zip = St